# Is it possible to relatively position an element OVER a relatively positioned canvas?

Tags: css, html, canvas

Here is my problem:

I have a `canvas` element that I center in the `documentElement` using JavaScript. It has a relative position so that it can still flow nicely with the p elements above and below it. I would like to put another p element on top of the canvas. Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
var element=document.getElementById("my_canvas_element");

while(element.parentElement){
    offset_x+=element.offsetLeft;
    offset_y+=element.offsetTop;
    element=element.parentElement;
}

my_p_element.style.left=offset_x+"px";
my_p_element.style.top=offset_y+"px";
```

This will accurately position `my_p_element` at the top left corner of the canvas element as long as I set `my_p_element`'s CSS position to absolute. Is there any way to position `my_p_element` in the top left corner of my relatively positioned canvas element using only CSS?

That is, is there a way to place a p element in the top left corner of a relatively positioned canvas using only CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: Not really. Relative positioning moves the element **relative to itself** not another element.

Comment: That's true, but I can still adjust the absolute left position of the relatively positioned canvas element using JavaScript, which I didn't think was possible before. Of course it's not positioned over any other elements.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping your canvas and paragraph elements in a div with that div
position:relative.

Then you can position:absolute the canvas and paragraphs as needed relative to the parent div.

[image]

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:0px;}
#wrapper{position:relative; border:1px solid blue; width:300px; height:300px; }
#p1{position:absolute; top:-15px; border:1px solid green;}
#canvas{position:absolute; border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<div id=wrapper>
  <p id=p1>I'm a top-left paragraph element</p>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually works pretty nicely, but I'd still have to horizontally center the div in JavaScript, unless there's some way to shrink a div to fit its contents. I can't use a fixed width and height because my canvas element resizes to fit the client window's smallest dimension. I then want to center it on the other dimension. I wish I could just put tags inside the canvas tag, that would be sweet.